# Who should own /usr/share/elasticsearch/ in order to Elasticsearch to start

Tags: elasticsearch, chown

I'm starting with elasticsearch and noticed that in order to startup elasticsearch the directory

*/usr/share/elasticsearch/*
and all subs need to be own by elasticsearch:elasticsearch.

If it's own by root with 755 permissions elasticsearch is throwing :

```
Starting elasticsearch: bash: /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch: Permission denied
```

Is it expecticated as even if root is the owner elastic should be able to startup as other can r+x?

Comment: On my RPM installled ES servers (1.7 and 2.4.6) root owns all of this. 755 means anyone should be able to execute so that makes sense. Only the plugins directory is owned by the "elasticsearch" user.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins Thanks for the comment. It's also what I was expected but in my case I needed to own /usr/share/elasticsearch with elasticsearch user and group to be able to startup (that lead to something else going on in my case).